# Firebase database data structure

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very newbie question.
I'm pretty new to nosql data structure therefore I'm struggling to create a simple data model in Firebase DB (which I'll have to later access via iOS app).
The data structure is pretty simple:

**Verbs**

- verb1
- verb2
- verb3
- verb*n*

**Adjectives**

- adjective1
- adjective2
- adjective3
- adjective*n*

**Nouns**

- noun1
- noun2
- noun3
- noun*n*

The point is that Firebase is asking me for a key couple for each value, while I have a one to many relationship.

Thanks for any help!

---

Edit:

I thought was clear, but I was eventually wrong.
Each Verb, Adjective, Noun is unique like in a word dictionary.

Therefore under the "table" verbs we will have:

1. Have
2. Hate
3. Move
4. Run
5. Turn
   [etc...]

under the Adjectives something like:

1. Adorable
2. Useless
3. Editable
   [etc...]

Basically I'll need to retrieve all the verbs-adjectives-nouns later from my mobile app to form sentences.

Comment: Can you update your question with your use case? Why one to many? What are you doing with the data? Does each word need to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what 'key couple' means - maybe a key:value pair?

If so a structure like this would be one option

```
Verbs
  -Y9j9j9jd9jd: verb1
  -Y8jsjjkksds: verb2
Adjectives
  -UY99jsiosij: adjective1
  -Y8hisi9jds9: adjective2
Nouns
  -Y78h9jsdjfd: noun1
  -Y8jsjosoos9: noun2
```

Each child of Verbs, Adjectives and Nouns is now a key: value pair with the -Y.... being the key and the verb, adjective or noun being the value.

The -Y... key is generated by childByAutoId and is a Firebase function call that creates a unique key.

Using this structure would allow you to access Y8jsjjkksds to get verb2 which would enable a one to many relationship - although that relationship was not outlined in your question so I am not sure if more data is needed.

Or, per the below comment - an excellent good observation - is that the words may been to be discreet so a structure like this would work:

```
Verbs
  verb1: true
  verb2: true
Adjectives
  adjective1: true
  adjective2: true
Nouns
  noun1: true
  noun2: true
```

Comment: I expect that the items in each collection have to be unique, so that it's more a *set* than an *array*. In that case, I'd model it was either the verb as the key (`"verb1": true, "verb2": true`) or with a key derived from the verb (`"verb1hash": true, "verb2hash": true`) to prevent duplicates.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Excellent point. Updated the answer with that option. Hopefully the OP will clarify the question.